# Speed of a Java Socket on LAN

Tags: sockets, lan

I am just wondering if the speed of data going through a LAN socket should be relatively instantaneous or is there still a delay even though it is a local network.

Comment: The speed of a network depends on a lot of factors (too broad to discuss here).  Have a look at the `ping` command (available on many operating systems), and try it on tour network.

Comment: Instantaneous relative to what? Of course there is *some* delay.

Comment: You can measure latency, it's the best way to find out. Nothing will be faster than theoretical limit. Plus, 'Java ' part of title is almost irrelevant -- JVM runtime shouldn't introduce any significant delay to underlying OS Sockets API.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have been taught, The speed of the data is based more on your hardware than your software. Depending on if you use ethernet cables (faster) or WiFi waves (slower), the speed will vary. However, despite this, you should still expect nearly instantaneous speeds.

Comment: Thanks for the help!